# Mutual SSL in WSO2 API Manager 3.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

While trying to configure Mutual SSL for an API, below error is thrown:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-01-14 11:43:09,542] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.authenticator.MutualSSLAuthenticator} - Mutual SSL authentication failure
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-01-14 11:43:09,544]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} - API authentication failure due to Invalid Credentials

<ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security"><ams:code>900901</ams:code><ams:message>Invalid Credentials</ams:message><ams:description>Invalid Credentials. Make sure you have provided the correct security credentials</ams:description></ams:fault>
```

For this API, only "Transport Level Security" is kept mandatory whereas "Application Level Security" is kept as optional. Please advise on how to achieve mutual SSL working on the wso2 API Manager 3.0.0

Comment: This is possibly due to not sending the certificate in the request. Can you confirm?

Comment: In this setup, nginx is fronting as proxy server for wos2 api manager. SSL is enabled on Nginx as well. Tested using certificate configured on nginx as well as wso2 default certificate(localhost) present in wso2carbon.jks

Answer (score 1):

If you are watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVwoZGTZpQs), you will figure out how to achieve mutual SSL working on the WSO2 API Manager 3.0.0. It has clearly explained how mutual SSL working with WSO2 API manager

Comment: Hi how does mutual SSL work in wso2 , i am following the link https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-security/api-authentication/secure-apis-using-mutual-ssl/ it works in local but not in our production environment, where where have different DNS other than localhost

Comment: @KitteyKotte please try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64712201/mutual-ssl-connection-issue-in-wso2-3-0-0-apim