# Mutual SSL connection issue in WSO2 3.0.0 APIM

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, wso2

how does mutual SSL work in wso2, I am following the link https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-security/api-authentication/secure-apis-using-mutual-ssl/
it works in local where domain is localhost

But in our production environment, where our gateway is fronted with AWS ALB it does not work, for the same certificate and key which I used in local.

Error in logs

ERROR - MutualSSLAuthenticator Mutual SSL authentication failure
[2020-11-02 10:20:56,302] ERROR - MutualSSLAuthenticator Mutual SSL authentication failure

On wso2 documentation is mentioned that
the following prerequisites need to be met by the Load Balancer.

Terminate the mutual SSL connection from the client.
Pass the client SSL certificate to the Gateway in an HTTP Header

But from AWS team i came to know that "So is not possible to achieve Client<=>Backend TLS mutual authentication with an ALB in the middle."

It will be great if someone will be able to clear the confusion

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, the Load balancer terminates the SSL connection with the wso2 server.

Hence, you have to pass the certificate in a special header when invoking the request.

**X-WSO2-CLIENT-CERTIFICATE**

If the certificate is not presented by default (due to the SSL termination from the LB level), it checks the above header and extracts the certificate. That certificate will be checked against the client-trustore.jks and authenticated.

The following is the logic in which was extracted and verified.

https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/gateway/handlers/Utils.java#L386

```
public static X509Certificate getClientCertificate(org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext axis2MessageContext)
            throws APIManagementException {

        Map headers =
                (Map) axis2MessageContext.getProperty(org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext.TRANSPORT_HEADERS);
        Object sslCertObject = axis2MessageContext.getProperty(NhttpConstants.SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_X509);
        X509Certificate certificateFromMessageContext = null;
        if (sslCertObject != null) {
            X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) sslCertObject;
            certificateFromMessageContext = certs[0];
        }
        if (headers.containsKey(Utils.getClientCertificateHeader())) {

            try {
                if (!isClientCertificateValidationEnabled() || APIUtil
                        .isCertificateExistsInTrustStore(certificateFromMessageContext)){
                    String base64EncodedCertificate = (String) headers.get(Utils.getClientCertificateHeader());
                    if (base64EncodedCertificate != null) {
                        base64EncodedCertificate = URLDecoder.decode(base64EncodedCertificate).
                                replaceAll(APIConstants.BEGIN_CERTIFICATE_STRING, "")
                                .replaceAll(APIConstants.END_CERTIFICATE_STRING, "");

                        byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(base64EncodedCertificate);
                        try (InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)) {
                            X509Certificate x509Certificate = X509Certificate.getInstance(inputStream);
                            if (APIUtil.isCertificateExistsInTrustStore(x509Certificate)) {
                                return x509Certificate;
                            }else{
                                log.debug("Certificate in Header didn't exist in truststore");
                                return null;
                            }
                        } catch (IOException | CertificateException | APIManagementException e) {
                            String msg = "Error while converting into X509Certificate";
                            log.error(msg, e);
                            throw new APIManagementException(msg, e);
                        }
                    }

                }
            } catch (APIManagementException e) {
                String msg = "Error while validating into Certificate Existence";
                log.error(msg, e);
                throw new APIManagementException(msg, e);

            }

        }
        return certificateFromMessageContext;
    }
```

Hope the above will clarifies your concerns.

Thanks,
Dileepa

Comment: i tried to import cert in gateway client-trustore.jks but if certificate is getting dropped at LB, how to it will get validated wrt client-trustore.jks? i LB logs on AWS i didnt observe any certificate, and gateway logs i didn't see X-WSO2-CLIENT-CERTIFICATE

Comment: @Vivek you have to pass the certificate explicitly using the X-WSO2-CLIENT-CERTIFICATE header value in the request. `curl -k -X GET "https://localhost:8243/pizzashack/1.0.0/menu" -H "accept: application/json" -H "X-WSO2-CLIENT-CERTIFICATE: <Certificate-Here>"`. If the header is getting dropped, try changing the header value which used to check the certificate from the gateway. please refer to the end of the [https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-security/api-authentication/secure-apis-using-mutual-ssl/]  for changing the header value.

Comment: I tried passing certificate in the header  X-WSO2-CLIENT-CERTIFICATE and as well as key of certificate but it did not work still same error in gateway logs.

Comment: I walked through the code again. the only possibilities that you are getting the `MutualSSLAuthenticator Mutual SSL authentication failure` error are the following. 1 `enable_client_validation = false` is not configured in the deployment.toml file  2. the client certificate is not in the expected format  3.  certificate is not existing in the client trust store. Can you check the above 3 places?. Note : the certificate which is sending through the header should have begin certificate and end certificates as it is in the crt file.please refer the code mentioned in the answer

Comment: do I need to pass key also with client certificate as mentioned in wso2 documentation

Comment: i tried again as per you sugession but still no luck, same error i am getting```{
    "fault": {
        "code": 900901,
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "description": "Invalid Credentials. Make sure you have provided the correct security credentials"
    }
}```

Comment: still error in logs [2020-11-09 05:41:32,305] ERROR - MutualSSLAuthenticator Mutual SSL authentication failure

Comment: By default, the WSO2 API Manager retrieves the client certificate from the X-WSO2-CLIENT-CERTIFICATE HTTP header. In order to change the header,

From <https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-security/api-authentication/secure-apis-using-mutual-ssl/>

Comment: in cloudwatch logs, i can see this header X-WSO2-CLIENT-CERTIFICATE HTTP, but still 401 error is coming

Comment: can you enable debug logs for the following classes and invoke. org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.Utils
 org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.authenticator.MutualSSLAuthenticator   it may give some information on why it is failing. please refer https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/logging-and-monitoring/logging/setting-up-logging/ for enabling debug logs for those classes.

Comment: when i tried all above suggestions with local(allinone) component it does not work, error in log  WARN - SourceHandler I/O error: General SSLEngine problem

Comment: X-WSO2-CLIENT-CERTIFICATE: (Base64 encoded public cert)--------- gateway is not reading this header, if I give the same certificate and the wrong certificate, in both case, same mutual authentication error –

Comment: i am getting below error now, any thoughts? ......................EBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 << "WWW-Authenticate: Mutual SSL realm="WSO2 API Manager" OAuth2 realm="WSO2 API Manager", error="invalid_token", error_description="The access token expired"[\r][\n]"  06:56:32 [2020-12-08 04:56:32,979] WARN - SourceHandler I/O error: General SSLEngine problem  06:56:35 [2020-12-08 04:56:35,294] WARN - SourceHandler I/O error: General SSLEngine problem